# Firebase .validate rule for child record

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've a users database on firebase realtime database.

My structure is:

Users
  -> uid
    -> user_infos (in this level I've a property called: 'cpf')

So I created a .validate rule for cpf:

```
  {
  "rules": {
     "users": {
        "$user_id": {
           "$cpf": {
               ".validate": "!data.exists()"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I try to save user, I receive a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error.

I'm using firebase javascript lib, 3.4.1

the method that I use for save user is:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set(userDb);
```

My intention is that cpf property to be unique on database.

Thank you.

Comment: Your rules look fine. The only way I can quickly see this failing is when `userDb.id` is an empty string.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my question, the older question didn't satisfy my necessity. Thx

Comment: what if you try a `.write` instead of a `.validate` and use the rule `".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"`"

Comment: Hi @FowotadeBabajide, I did as you recommended and got the same error: /users/JaL6XNubCGUDIACUlIzTkaztWc83 failed: permission_denied for an existing cpf and for a non existing too.

Comment: hmmm, just to be sure @NatanDeitch, are you sure you're writing to the correct node? e.g `users/user_IDxxxxx/cpf_IDxxx` `=> then => set()`

Comment: Hmm, what I'm doing is the following: firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).set(userDb); cpf is inside userDb. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, doing manually a verification to firebase. It's not so great solution, but worked.

Comment: You should post your solution so if anyone else has the same problem they can try your solution.